# Simultaneous Exporting of Reports in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Is it possible in access to export several reports to PDF at the same time. If yes, can anyone please let me know how to do this?
I have searched much for this online but could not find an answer. 
Thank you for your time in responding to my questions.

nupur

Comment: By the way, how many reports are we talking about? Does the export take an unacceptable amount of time. As TexasTubbs suggest, you might consider exporting them sequentially instead of simultaneously.

Comment: By _at the same time_ do you mean one PDF with 3 reports in it?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible "At the same time" because VBA by itself is not multi-threaded.  Each report must be run, and exported in succession.  This whole process can be automated using VBA to make it easier.

An example of how to accomplish this in an automated fashion would be to create a macro for each report which first runs it, then exports the result.  Use a VBA module to call each macro in succession.  You may need to implement a WAIT in between each call to the macros to allow them time to execute.

Once completed, all the user has to do is initiate the VBA module (a button click is simplest), and wait...  The reports will spit out one at a time automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SendObject method of the DoCmd object:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214075(v=office.12).aspx

```
DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "Employees", acFormatPDF, _
    "Nancy Davolio; Andrew Fuller", "Joan Weber", , _
    "Current Spreadsheet of Employees", , False
```

Comment: You will have to say a bit more than that. Your question is quite vague. Post some code and a note on what is not working. You can edit your post and add the details.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Macro for each report you want to export and then invoke multiple instances of Access by using the Shell command (VBA does not wait on this one to complete).

For example, if you have a report named `Report1`, create a macro called `PrintReport1` that exports the PDF and then closes the database.

Then in your VBA code run:

```
Shell("msaccess ""C:\DatabasePath\Database.accdb"" /x PrintReport1")
Shell("msaccess ""C:\DatabasePath\Database.accdb"" /x PrintReport2")
```

No comment on how the performance may be on this, but it would work.

Comment: Wouldn't the databases be locked in the event that a report was designed to first do any updates, or pre-load results into an aggregate table prior to report rendering?

Comment: By default a database can be opened several times by the same user (and multiple users in the case of a network share) - unless the database has been opened as *exclusive*. Tables are not locked, but rows are. If there is a complex sequence of updating and temp data caching, I would not recommend even attempting parallel exporting unless you have a really good handle on the sequencing.

Comment: Good to know, I was always under the impression that MS Access enforces table locking regardless of the open state during updates.  Maybe that was the case in the old JET days... :\

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar; I have a Quarterly Sales report I need to run based on the 3 reports for each month in the quarter.

I found a utility called PDFTK

https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

that seems to do what I want, after the reports are run, it will combine them into one report.

My problem is running it from DOS deep in subdirectories.  I created a batch file that runs the utility and concatenates M1, M2, and M3 reports into one file, but getting MSFT Access to open, then change to the correct directory, and call the batch file and somehow get it to know that I'm trying to concatenate the files in this particular subdirectory is problematic.

This is my batch file I have gotten so far:

```
pdftk m1.pdf m2.pdf m3.pdf cat output salesreportqtr.pdf 
del m1.pdf
del m2.pdf
del m3.pdf
```

But, because the directory changes each time, I can't get the program to call it correctly.  If the USER pops out to DOS (Impossible for my users, they refuse to even LOOK at DOS) and run the program, all will work right.

Comment: Does this handle the actual export of MSFT Access reports?